# Local notifications - repeat Interval in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, localnotification

I want to repeat local notification every week, before iOS10 there is `repeatInterval`, but i am not able to find anything suitable to repeat notifications in iOS10. 
`TimeTrigger` and `calendarTrigger` both have repeat as true or false, where can i apply repeat as weekly, daily, monthly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
func scheduleNotification(at date: Date, body: String) {     
    let triggerWeekly = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerWeekly, repeats: true)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Dont Forget"
    content.body = body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    //content.categoryIdentifier = "todoList"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }
```